# Invalid input on simple MEL expression

Tags: mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

Learning Mule and MEL. Attempting to set the Expression of the first node of a Choice card in Anypoint Studio.

According to the [docs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/mule-expression-language-reference#context-objects-variables-and-fields) an example of a basic logical operator is `#[(a == b) && (c != d)]`

However when I enter `#[ (payload.myVar != 'val1') && (payload.myVar != 'val2') ]` Anypoint says the ampersand is invalid input.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please share the complete error message, all lines, as text. Also the value of payload.myVar.

Comment: Message Flow Error: Invalid input '&', expected Attribute<'@('(Name:Value)+')'> or :

There is no value in payload yet as this is an Error display by the Studio parser upon save

Comment: One problem is that I'm in Anypoint 4 and was looking at docs for 3.9, so there's that

Comment: I have proposed a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying a MEL expression in Mule 4.x. MEL was the expression language for Mule 3.x. In Mule 4 it was replaced by [DataWeave 2.0](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave). MEL is not supported in Mule 4. See the [Dataweave documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave) for more information on the language and features.

As a rule of thumb Anypoint Studio 6.x is to develop Mule 3 applications and Anypoint Studio 7.x is for developing Mule 4.x applications.

In Mule 4.x the equivalent expression would be:

`#[ (payload.myVar != "val1") and (payload.myVar != "val2") ]`